Can a record-triggered flow retrigger itself?
The question pretty much explains itself. Can a record-triggered flow retrigger itself if the entry conditions are met? I know that an after save flow can trigger other flows/triggers with the update element if the conditions are met. But I wanted to know if this will also trigger the same flow again?

If you review the process outlined in the trigger order of execution documentation you will see that record triggered flows are invoked at step 3 or 14, depending on whether they are before or after save. You can also see that async paths in such flows are initiated from step 20, after the records have been committed to the database.
So, to your question, a record triggered flow cannot cause itself to be re-invoked on the same records in the same DML operation without there also being some other automation, such as a workflow rule (step 11, and specifically 11.b), that causes the save process to be re-executed.
